# Interest on security deposits paid to landlords, in Michigan?

Tags: united-states, interest, rent, landlord

Does the state of Michigan require landlords to put security deposits in interest bearing financial institutions?

Answer (score 4):

NO.  The legislation requires the landlord to deposit it in a bank.  Check out pages 7-10 of the linked document.  There is no mention of interest.

The second clause, I believe, is probably for large landlords who hold hundreds of thousands of dollars of security.

http://www.legislature.mi.gov/documents/publications/tenantlandlord.pdf

> Q4
>
> Once collected, what must the landlord do with the security deposit?
>   The landlord must either:
>
> a) Deposit the money with a regulated financial institution (e.g.,
>   bank), OR
>
> b) Deposit a cash bond or surety bond, to secure the entire deposit,
>   with the Secretary of State. ( Note: If the landlord does this, he or
>   she may use the money at any time, for any purpose.) The bond ensures
>   that there is money available to repay the tenant’s security deposit

Answer (score 3):

No. The [full text](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/%28S%28ko3cpp45gs02yy45ua0yuqmj%29%29/mileg.aspx?page=GetMCLDocument&objectname=mcl-act-348-of-1972) of the Landlord-Tenant Act (specifically, section 554.614 of Act 348 of the year 1972) makes no mention of this. Searching the law for ["interest"](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/%28S%28ko3cpp45gs02yy45ua0yuqmj%29%29/mileg.aspx?page=getObject&objectName=mcl-554-614&highlight=interest) doesn't yield anything of interest (pardon the pun).

Specifically, section 554.604 of the same law states that:

> (1) The security deposit shall be deposited in a regulated financial
>   institution. A landlord may use the moneys so deposited for any
>   purposes he desires if he deposits with the secretary of state a cash
>   bond or surety bond written by a surety company licensed to do
>   business in this state and acceptable to the attorney general to
>   secure the entire deposits up to $50,000.00 and 25% of any amount
>   exceeding $50,000.00. The attorney general may find a bond
>   unacceptable based only upon reasonable criteria relating to the
>   sufficiency of the bond, and shall notify the landlord in writing of
>   his reasons for the unacceptability of the bond.
>
> (2) The bond shall be for the benefit of persons making security
>   deposits with the landlord. A person for whose benefit the bond is
>   written or his legal representative may bring an action in the
>   district, common pleas or municipal court where the landlord resides
>   or does business for collection on the bond.

While it does sound like the landlord is required to deposit the money in a bank or other secured form, e.g. the Secretary of State, he/she isn't required to place it in an account that will earn interest.